# Cutting excessive trails off a float

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I am getting numbers back from postgre db in float format and when trying to print them in my html page they took too much space. How do I cut the excessive precision number using a quick JS function? i.e:

```
98.7776 --> 98.7
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var num = 98.7776;
var result = num.toFixed(1);
```